# Output first line of temporary file

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to checkout the latest git commit with the word "merge" inside the commit message. I am trying to output the latest git commit line to see if my script is working so far

```
tempfile=$((mktemp))
tempfile2=$((mktemp))

git log --oneline >> $tempfile
grep -i "merge" $tempfile | head -1 > $tempfile2
cat $tempfile2
```

I was expecting the script to output just one line containing "merge" however it outputs the whole log. I actually just want to take the commit id and git checkout the latest "merge" file to a detached head state. If anyone could help me with what to do next I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using tempfiles instead of just piping the output of `git` directly to `grep`?

Comment: You can use `grep -m 1` to stop after printing 1 match.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: `git log --oneline | grep -i merge -m 1`

Comment: Right `GNU` and `BSD`  `grep(1)` has `-m`  but it is not define/required by posix. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/grep.html, the alternative is `head` afaik.